# Sudoku code to return True or False

Tags: python-2.7

The procedure needs to return True or False if the given input (nxn square list of digits) conforms to sudoku or not. Given list should return True is no digit in either row or column occurs more than once

My code is producing an error right now that says:

```
s[i][j] == s[i][j+1]:IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please suggest how to fix the above issue and any other to correct this  procedure

```
def check_sudoku(s):        
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i<len(s):
        while j<len(s):
            if s[i][j] == s[i][j+1]:
                return False
            j = j + 1
        i = i+1
    while j<len(s):
        while i<len(s):
            if s[i][j] == s[i+1][j]:
                return False
            i=i+1
        j=j+1
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

`j` should be less than `len(s)-1` because when it reaches `len(s)-1` then `j+1` is equal to `len(s)` and raises `IndexError`

Also I think `j` should be in range `len(s[i])-1` not `len(s)`